Допустимо ли применять статические методы, возвращающие экземпляр класса?
Относится ли данный прием к какому-либо паттерну проектирования? Допустимо ли его применять? Могут ли такие статические методы разных объектов взаимодействовать друг с другом (вызывать друг друга по цепочке)?

Дополнение.
Речь шла про вот такую конструкцию:
public class Solution
{
    public List<Project> Projects { get; }

    private Solution(params Project[] projects)
    {
        Projects = projects.ToList();
    }

    public static Solution CreateFromFile(string pathToFile)
    {
        return new Solution(
            ProjectFileHelper.ExtractFilePaths(
                File.ReadAllText(pathToFile), 
                FileExtension.Sln)
                    .Select(path => Project.CreateFromFile(path))
                    .ToArray());
    }
}

Три класса, три статических метода вызывают друг друга по цепочке. Мозг уже сломал - никак не могу придумать ничего лучше. Если оставить так, то тогда непонятно, как это тестировать.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

К тому, что написали EvgeniyZ и tym32167, могу ещё добавить различные десериализаторы, парсеры. Например:
// struct DateTime
public static DateTime FromBinary (long dateData);
public static DateTime Parse (ReadOnlySpan<char> s, IFormatProvider? provider);


Спасибо за ответ! Добавил к вопросу дополнение с примером моей ситуации. Те же парсеры, к примеру, работают только с теми данными, которые они получают в виде аргументов. У меня проблема в том, что если перенести те данные, с которыми работает статический метод, в его аргументы, то полетит вся инкапсуляция.

CreateFromFile - типичный десериализатор. У вас вопрос поменялся - оказывается, вы хотите избавиться от статики. Так его и перепишите.

Нет, не от статики. От нее несложно избавиться если потребуется (по крайней мере, пока мне так кажется). Меня смущает то, что метод CreateFromFile класса Solution вызывает метод CreateFromFile класса Project (а он по такому же принципу вызвает следующий CreateFromFile класса CodeFile). Это модель проекта Visual Studio. В результате все три класса получаются жестко связанными, т.к. напрямую обращаются друг к другу. Можно ли это как-то исправить, и нужно ли пытаться?

Если это вызывает у вас дискомфорт - то избавляйтесь :-) "нужно ли пытаться" - так вы сами определитесь, нужно или нет? У меня поход такой: пока сомневаетесь - ничего не трогайте. Если вруг появятся аргументы за замену - замените. В Студии же это работает. Чем не аргумент?

"В результате все три класса получаются жестко связанными" не из-за кода, а из-за модели данных, обработка которой запрограммирована этим кодом. Кардинально поменять код можно только изменив обрабатываемую модель. Это главное, все остальные рассуждения, в общем-то, - болтовня. Сейчас объектная модель приложения очень хорошо соответствует объекту.

Мысль понятна, спасибо за помощь! Я просто думал, что может есть какой-то хитрый способ соблюсти DIP, о котором я просто не знаю по неграмотности)
